# Waiting for process to start when restarting Perl script under Idea

Tags: macos, perl, debugging, intellij-idea

I wrote simple Hello world Perl script and ran it successfully under Idea debugger once. I was able to step over statements, see values in debugger etc.

But only once.

Next time debugging doesn't start saying

```
Waiting for process to start...
```

I need to restart Idea to be able to debug again.

How to fix?

Comment: Is this on Windows ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland ah, it's on Macos

Comment: When I tried this on macOS 11.2.3. and "Run"->"Debug.." from the menu, it gives an error *"Can't locate Devel/Camelcadedb.pm in @INC"*

Comment: More information of how to enable debugging is [here](https://github-wiki-see.page/m/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA/wiki/Perl-Debugger)

Comment: @HåkonHægland me too, then I have installed this

Answer (score 1):

It works fine on macOS 11.2.3 with perlbrew perl version 5.32.1:

As noted on the [wiki](https://github-wiki-see.page/m/Camelcade/Perl5-IDEA/wiki/Perl-Debugger) page, you need to first install the [Devel::Camelcadedb](https://metacpan.org/dist/Devel-Camelcadedb/view/lib/Devel/Camelcadedb.pod) module. I installed [Bundle::Camelcade](https://metacpan.org/dist/Bundle-Camelcade) which includes the above module.

When I now choose "Run"->"Debug.." from the IntelliJ menu the second time it shows:

```
/Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew exec -q --with perl-5.32.1 /Users/hakonhaegland/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.32.1/bin/perl -I/Users/hakonhaegland/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld/lib -d:Camelcadedb /Users/hakonhaegland/IdeaProjects/HelloWorld/Hello.pl
Waiting for process to start...
Listening for the IDE connection at 0.0.0.0:49310...
Connecting to localhost:49310...
Connected
Hello world!
var = 3

Process finished with exit code 0
Disconnected
```